# How to count number of unique pairs in two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a simple MySQL table with columns author, recipient and message.

Both author and recipient are users.

Bob can write to Alice and Alice can write back, resulting in

| author | recipient | message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Alice | Hi, Alice |
| Alice | Bob | Hi back, Bob |
| Bob | Alice | How are you, Alice? |

The result I need to get is

| pair | count |
| --- | --- |
| Bob, Alice | 3 |

But I keep getting

| pair | count |
| --- | --- |
| Bob, Alice | 2 |
| Alice, Bob | 1 |

I tried using CONCAT of the names as the key, but I am unable to get to right result. I keep running into this result:

| pair | count |
| --- | --- |
| Bob, Alice | 3 |
| Alice, Bob | 3 |

I tried unions, joins, subqueries and plenty combinations of thereof but I am unable to get a clean result without duplicities and I worry I am far deep in the rabbit hole to see a simple solution.

The order of the names is not important though if they would be in alphabetical order it would be nice bonus.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the functions `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` to create unique pairs:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEAST(author, recipient), ',', GREATEST(author, recipient)) pair, 
       COUNT(*) count
FROM tablename
GROUP BY pair
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c3ea1539b838df3fe63ee1100d97ba63).
Results:

| pair | count |
| --- | --- |
| Alice,Bob | 3 |

Comment: Sure thing, stack overflow prevented me from doing that yesterday because there's timelimit before which I was unable to accept the answer. Thanks again!